# Binding two matrices with different row sizes

Tags: r, matrix, bind

I'm trying to bind two matrices by columns in R. the matrices have different row sizes.
Here is an example : 
This is matrix 1 :

```
 M <- matrix(0, nr = 3, nc = 2)
```

And matrix 2:

```
 N <- matrix(2, nr = 1, nc = 3)
```

the output needs to be something like :

```
0    0    2   2   2
0    0    NA  NA  NA
0    0    NA  NA  NA
```

Even though the idea is very simple. I didn't manage to implement it or find a solution on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack that could be turned into a function if you need to repeat this process:

```
cbind(M, rbind(N, matrix(NA, nr = nrow(M) - nrow(N), nc = ncol(N))))
```

Comment: Thank you @ulfelder that's exactly what I did.